# Jersey equivalent of RestEasy @Form

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, resteasy

I want to bundle method parameters of jax-rs annotated interface (client proxy) into a pojo class. As an implementation of jax-rs im using Jersey. How can i achieve the same thing as i can do with RestEasy @Form annotation but with jersey? I have not find anything useful.

Resteasy example:

```
public class MyForm {

   @FormParam("stuff")
   private int stuff;


   @HeaderParam("myHeader")
   private String header;

}

@POST
@Path("/myservice")
public void post(@Form MyForm form) {...}
```

What would be its equivalent in jersey?

Comment: On the server you can use `@BeanParam`, but it is not supported for the client proxy.

Comment: @peeskillet Unfortunately i need to use client proxy. Are there any possible approaches if i dont want to end up with tons of arguments in every proxy method?

Comment: Use the [overloaded `getResource` method](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/ext/proxy-client/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/client/proxy/WebResourceFactory.java#L138) where you can pass headers and form data (in the form of `Form`).

Comment: You can accept `Form` and `@Context HttpHeaders` on the server, or use `@BeanParam`. For the client proxy, you don't need to pass these arguments. Just use the overloaded `newResource` method and pass the form data and headers. You can pass null the args.

Comment: @peeskillet How exactly am i supposed to work with the Form object. wouldn't you mind to provide an example?

Lets say my pojo class in the client proxy has fields annotated with `@HeaderParam(value="header") @FormParam(value="formparam") and @PathParam(value="path")`
am i supposed to put all those values into a Form object?
like `form.param("header","somestring").param("path";"anotherstring");`
`ClientProxy.method(PojoClass clazz);`

Comment: Have a look at [this test](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/b23f1e57ad7bc8fbde08). It might be a bug with the path templates. It seems it expects a `@PathParam` as a parameter. I have to look into it further. In the test I just added it